# Правильно ли говорить "по-любому".

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня раздражает, когда в разговорной речи употребляют "по-любому". Например: "Я по-любому сегодня не успею сделать". Допустимо ли так говорить?

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/9454/грамотная-речь-выражение-по-любому

Answer (score 1):

В разговорной речи, вероятно, да. Понимаете, так говорят, что тут можно сделать? Смотрите в толковых словарях, их же навалом. Естественно, в новых, не в Ушакове и, упаси бог, не в Дале. )))